# NOOBS and monitor not working

Tags: boot-issues

I see this question answered but none of the solves have helped.  I am trying to boot a B+, I have an older viewsonic LCD with HDMI, a 16 GB SD formatted and loaded with the unzipped software from the Rasp Pi site.  no boot, no recognition of the mmonitor, no recog when plugged into my laptop.  I don't have a hard line to internet but do have a brand new dongle for WiFi and a hotspot; new keyboard and mouse.

Ideas anyone?  This is my first venture into RPi but I've been working with Arduino for a couple years.  A big thanks.

SD formatter: 
 https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/eula_windows/index.html

NOOBS version:  https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/

Comment: The number of green LED flashes can be used to diagnose boot problems.  Have a google.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another device like personal computer with that HDMI cable and see if it works (the HDMI cable is working properly), If you are using the unzipped NOOBS then there shouldn't be a problem. If The HDMI cable is working then you should think about sending back that RPi to Seller and requesting a new one

Comment: Thank you.  I tested the monitor and cable and both work fine with my laptop.  I've been reading about ssh-ing the start up and code and the option of headless operation.  Ideally, this set up was to run the shopbot so I could free up my laptop.